# How do I make Request Review available to everyone in Team Foundation Server 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

When i log into TFS from Visual Studio 2012 and go to check in code i can see the "Request Review" option under actions. When others log in they can not see that option under the same project. I have looked through the security permissions and can not find a setting to allow it for specific groups.

Do any one know where this setting may be?

Comment: Code Reviews in VS2012 require the Premium or Ultimate edition, could that be it?

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean by "log in". Do they have a "My Work" page in Team Explorer?

Comment: The version was the issue.